# How to iterate on an array and print table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to iterate over an array and make a table row with its elements.
The coinlist is an array of object containing coin symbol and price.
Is there any way to print table row with map function.

```
      <tbody>
            {coinlist.map((coin) => {
              return {
               
                 <tr>
                        <td>{coin.symbol}</td>
                        <td>{coin.price}</td>
                 </tr> 
            } })} 
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Price</th>
       
      </tr>
     {coinlist.map(coin)=>(
 <tr>
        <td>{coin.symbol}</td>
        <td>{coin.price}</td>
       
      </tr>
))}
     
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out the object fields which make up the table row you can either `console.log` the entire object which makes up the row or each individual field. Something along the lines of:

```
<tbody>
    {coinlist.map((coin) => {
        console.log(coin); // see the entire coin object
        console.log(`symbol: ${coin.symbol} price: ${coin.price}`); // see individual fields of interest
        return {  
            <tr>
               <td>{coin.symbol}</td>
               <td>{coin.price}</td>
             </tr> 
         } 
     })} 
</tbody>
```

Hopefully that helps